# Moment Js timezone function not changing the date

Tags: angular, typescript, momentjs

I have a date and time in UTC time and I would like to convert it to my local time ("Europe/Paris"). I tried using moment's timezone function however it does not change my date.

```js
var m = moment.tz(this.startTime, 'Europe/Paris');
this.startTime = m.format("YYYY-MM-DD HH:mm")
```

startTime remains the same and does not change however if I console log m I can see the correct date is listed under the _d tag in the moment object.
[image: moment object output]

Answer (score 0):

Try to use it with another order.

`const newTime = moment(this.startTime, 'YYYY-MM-DD HH:mm').tz('Europe/Paris')`